# Photoshop Scripting with Applescript — can't open image with "choose file"

Tags: applescript, photoshop

I know I'm missing something incredibly simple here, but I can't figure out what it is. If I use the following script:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5.1"
open file "path:to:some:file"
end tell
```

it works no problem, but if I try to use the "choose file" dialog everything falls apart:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5.1"
    set myFile to choose file
    open myFile
end tell
```

I get an error

```
error "Adobe Photoshop CS5.1 got an error: File some object wasn’t found." number -43
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try appending `as POSIX file` onto the `choose file`? Your first script suggests that the `open` command only takes file references in a certain way.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, Photoshop CS5.1 dropped support for opening alias based file references.

You'll need to convert the path to a string and prefix the myFile variable with file.

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5.1"
    set myFile to (choose file) as string
    open file myFile
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in Photoshop CS3. I don't have CS5 so I can't test it.

An easier alternative would be to use:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS3"
activate
tell application "System Events"
key code 31 using command down
end tell
end tell
```

You could also try Automator.